# Why is my asp.net mvc application now asking for .map files when I check with Fiddler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I started to notice when using Fiddler that my ASP.NET MVC application is now making requests for CSS map files.

Does anyone know how I can stop this happening.  Here is my bundle config:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                "~/Content/css/*.css"
                ));
```

Comment: It would help to include the fiddler logs

Comment: how did you manage to include the map file in your bundle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is looking for .map file such as

```
bootstrap-theme.css.map
bootstrap.css.map
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/css-preprocessors) is the more information about map.